# VBA solver with incorporated loop - solution not found

Tags: excel, vba, loops, solver

FYI i am a major noob at VBA, so don't be too tough on me!

I have tried to write a code, with the goal of creating a solver in VBA, which should loop multiple times throughout the data sheet. Every loop is not dependent on the prior loop.

The function should maximize the revenue for a given day - the formula is a sumproduct of some input cells in Excel and the variables that should change based on the constraints. The cells $I$:$AF$" & f should only take a value of either -1, 0 or 1.

I tested the solver with the constraints in the actual solver in excel for starters, which worked fine. So in order to loop it i decided to try and write it in VBA. I made it work without a loop, but with a loop, it states that it cannot find a solution for f= 83,84,85 (my test data is only 3 loops).

My data is arranged so that it can simply go down one row and iterate through, based on the "f" variable.

In the end it should iterate through a year, hence 365 times.

I tried disabling the MsgBox, just to see if it helped bypass it, but it didn't. PLEASE HELP!

**The code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub MultipleSolver()
    ' Variable declaration
    Dim f As Integer
    Dim s As Integer
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim m As Integer

    ' For Loop
    For f = 83 To 85
        s = f
        a = f + 66
        m = f + 99

        ' Solver setup
        SolverReset
        SolverOK SetCell:="$G$" & m, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$I$:$AF$" & f, _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

        ' Solver constraints
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$" & s, Relation:=2, FormulaText:="0"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$I$" & f, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="0"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$I$:$AF$" & f, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="1"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$I$:$AF$" & f, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="-1"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$I$:$AF$" & a, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="0"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$I$:$AF$" & a, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="-2"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$I$:$AF$" & f, Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"

        ' Solver Execution
        Dim result As Double
        result = Application.Run("Solver.xlam!SolverSolve", True)

        ' Check the result
        'Debug.Print "Solver Result for f = " & f & ": " & result

        ' If the result is 0, it indicates success
        'If result = 0 Then
            'MsgBox "Solver successfully found a solution for f = " & f
       ' Else
            'MsgBox "Solver did not find a solution for f = " & f
       ' End If

        ' Clear Solver settings
        Application.Run "Solver.xlam!SolverFinish", 1
    Next f
End Sub
```

Comment: `CellRef:="$I$:$AF$" & f`  that's not a valid range.  Did you mean `CellRef:="I" & f & ":AF" & f`  ?